# Simulating ActiveSync load from IOS and Android based client to and Exchange Server

Tags: iphone, android, ios, ipad, ios4

I'm developing an Exchange plugin that may effect ActiveSync operations. I am now looking for a quick way to generate a high load of sync/fetch operations that will simulate multiple ISO and Android devices which are tring to sync emails from 10,000 mailboxes.

It was able to load 10,000 mailbox to my Exchange server, but it seems I can not sync those mailboxes when sending a request with SyncKey=1 and Class=Email. It always fails with an object not found status code, even when the mailbox is filled with messages.

But, as soon as I configured a real IOS or Android Exchange client with a specific mailbox, suddenly it's possible to sync the mailbox.

Is there an easy way to configure this initial state on all of those mailboxes, so I would be able to sync them all later with a simple Sync command (SyncKey=1 and Class=Email) ? Or do you have any other idea how to generate this kind of load?